# Restrict application access to users who are not part of AD Groups

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage, pingfederate

We are using `OAuth 2.0` for implementing SSO login to the users in our application.
Currently our application can be accessed to by all users who are part of the company domain and registered in Azure Active directory.

We are looking for the ways to restrict the users who are not part of our Azure Active Directory groups (we have 2 groups created currently)

Below is our middleware code which we are calling in `ConfigureService()` of `Startup.cs` class, It is responsible for authenticating the users;

**Startup.cs:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //configure my sso
    MySsoProvider.ConfigureSso(services, Configuration);

    services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
    //initialize azure provider
    services.AddTransient(CreateAzureBlobFileProvider);
    //ad app insight telemetry
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
}
```

**MySsoProvider.cs:**

```
public static void ConfigureSso(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration Configuration)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "PiCookie";
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = "PiCookie";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Ping";
    }).AddCookie("PingCookie", options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.MaxAge = new TimeSpan(0, 29, 0);
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 29, 0); //cookie exipration set to 29 minutes
    }).AddOAuth("Ping", options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = Configuration["abc-def-sso-clientid"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["abc-def-sso-secret"];

        options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-ping");

        options.Scope.Add("openid profile email");
        options.UsePkce = true;
        options.SaveTokens = true;

        options.AuthorizationEndpoint = Configuration["Ping:AuthorizationEndpoint"];
        options.TokenEndpoint = Configuration["Ping:TokenEndpoint"];
        options.UserInformationEndpoint = Configuration["Ping:UserInformationEndpoint"];

        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "immutable_id");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "given_name");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Surname, "family_name");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:openid:groups", "groups");

        options.Events = new OAuthEvents
        {
            OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

                var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                var user = JsonDocument.Parse(responseText);
                context.RunClaimActions(user.RootElement);
            }
        };
    });
}
```

In above method we are getting user groups in the response inside `options.Events` logic.

How we can check if the required groups are present in the claims information from Home Controller Action methods?

Appreciate for any sample code or references for achieving the required functionality.

Answer (score 0):

To restrict your application access to users from particular Azure AD groups, you can use Enterprise Application for your App Registration in Azure AD

Navigate to your Azure AD App Registration

In the overview, Configure for your organization, click on **Go to Enterprise Applications**

[image]

Under Manage, click on **properties** and set **Enabled for users to sign-in?** to yes and click on save

[image]

Select **Users and Groups** under Manage. Add your Azure AD groups who need access to your application

**Reference**: [Azure AD: Restrict Application Access To Users Belonging To A Group | Rahul Nath (rahulpnath.com)](https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/azure-ad-restrict-application-to-users-in-group/)